# String to DateTime format

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to convert `10/10/2010 12:00:00 a.m.` to dateTime . I am using this...

```
DateTime.ParseExact(item.Birthey, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

But I get `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Trim the `.` chars with replace method in the string and it will work. `Replace(".", ""),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply try the `Parse` or `ParseExact` with manipulation of string command like:

```
string stringDate= "10/10/2010 12:00:00 P.M.";
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(stringDate.Replace(".", ""));
```

You may also try the following code sample if, the raw data that you get has "a.m." ending in it. Just replace that characters:

```
string stringDate= "10/10/2010 12:00:00 a.m.";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate.Replace(".", ""), 
                                 "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I used that, but my new datetime has no time, it only has date. "10/10/2010 00:00:00"

Answer (score 1):

Try instead

```
  DateTime.ParseExact("10/10/2010 12:00:00 am", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null).Dump();
```

the `.` in `a.m.` are creating the problems. You can use Replace to remove the `.` (as in your date format `.` can only appear in `a.m.`, or `p.m.`

```
  DateTime.ParseExact("10/10/2010 12:00:00 a.m.".Replace(".",""), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null).Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null`. In your case it uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.